# How do I start Tor browser? It "exited unexpectedly"

Tags: installation, tor

First off, I'm new to linux but I'm learning fast.
I've been trying to install tor and privoxy just to see how things work and stuff
I tried with the terminal at first but it keeps failing, I tried using synaptic but it didn't work either.

Sometimes I get close and even get to see a shortcut on dash home and open it but `tor &` doesn't work and when I click the shortcut I get this

> Vidalia detected that the Tor software exited unexpectedly.
>   Please check the message log for recent warning or error messages.

error log

```
Jul 16 20:47:12.935 [Warning] /home/analytic4l/.tor-browser/Data/Tor is not owned by this user (analytic4l, 1000) but by root (0). Perhaps you are running Tor as the wrong user?
Jul 16 20:47:12.935 [Warning] Failed to parse/validate config: Couldn't access/create private data directory "/home/analytic4l/.tor-browser/Data/Tor"
Jul 16 20:47:12.935 [Error] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

chmod wont work

```
analytic4l@analytic4l-ER190AA-ABA-s7420n:~$ sudo chmod -R analytic4l: /home/analytic4l/.tor-browser
chmod: invalid mode: `analytic4l:'
Try `chmod --help' for more information.
```

Comment: "Please check the message log for recent warning or error messages." <-- So, what does the message log say?

Answer (score 4):

You've probably started Tor browser as root some time earlier. This has created files with owner `root` as you can see in the error output. Because you now run it as a different user, the files are not accessible/writeable by the user `analytic4l` and that's why it fails to start.

Fix this by changing ownership. Run in a terminal:

```
sudo chown -R analytic4l: /home/analytic4l/.tor-browser
```

Comment: it says invalid mode

Comment: @temporary Whoops! Fixed it. `chmod` should have been `chown`. Sorry.